# Errors when Upgrading Flex 3.2 to 3.5

Tags: actionscript-3, upgrade, apache-flex

Here's are the errors:

VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of allowInsecureDomain in _SwdModule_mx_core_FlexModuleFactory.
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable _SwdModule_mx_core_FlexModuleFactory is not defined.

SwdModule is a module used within the organization and there's an application that loads this (and various other modules) at run time.

I've read on other stack overflow and various web site that this error was caused because the modules and the main app. were compiled using different Flex SDKs.  I verified and checked up on this, but all of my SWFs are compiling using 3.5.

Can anyone think of anything else why this error would be occuring?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Framework RSLs?

Comment: James, no -- do I need to? 

First off -- I didn't even know what it was until I just read up on it in Adobe's doc.  Now, I've seen the *.swz in other projects before but never for this one.  

So, now that I'm upgrading from 3.2 to 3.5, does that mean I need an RSL.  If so, how do I go about implementing / acquiring and using one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have compiled on 3.5 then the problem is with a component SWC being moved to a different location from 3.2.

For instance: They moved the AdvancedDataGrid into the datavisualization.swc.  If you are using this then you'll need to add that swc to your build path.

There may be some other components that were moved too.

Take a look at the 3.5 release notes to compare your component locations with the new version:

http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/3/releasenotes_flex3_sdk.html

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler complain at compilation time that a component couldn't be resolved? It only complains at run-time. Also, I've placed all the *.swc into the sdk libs so they are all imported automatically. :(  Any other ideas?